# How to handle navigation that occurs inside a Tab in iPhone

Tags: navigation, iphone, tabs

I'm confused on how to handle navigation inside tabs in iPhone.

[image]

Questions:

1. Once the post is created, does it belong in the create tab?
2. If it doesn't, how an 'orphan' page should behave in iPhone, should I still show the tabs but no tab is selected?
3. In this example I can't have a back button because the post has been created, but in a case of a navigation within a tab, does the tab remain selected? Let's say I click Category > List of items > Item (which could have been reach from any other tab): the category tab remain selected and the back button added to each screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem with this example is that creating a post, which is a **mode**, is actually being presented in the same way as the list of categories, which is **a view** or a 'place' within the app. This means that after creating a post, there is no natural 'place' for the user to be returned to.

If all of the existing posts live inside the 'Categories' section, I would rename that tab "Posts", remove the 'Create' tab and replace it with a 'Create' button inside the posts tab. That way, the user will go into the Posts tab to create a post and stay in that section afterwards.

Comment: That was useful, I just wanted to make it really easy for users to create posts but I guess I could add an icon on the navigation bar then the back button would go back to the last tab you were in.